# Selenium (Python) - SELECT

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Right now my script go to page and open the second object from the drop down list, "Vijesti", before I get the error message.

*This is the error:*

> StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

From Selenium site:

> Thrown when a reference to an element is now “stale”.
>   Stale means the element no longer appears on the DOM of the page.
>   Possible causes of StaleElementReferenceException include, but not limited to:
>
> - You are no longer on the same page, or the page may have refreshed since the element was located.
> - The element may have been removed and re-added to the screen, since it was located. Such as an element being relocated. This can happen typically with a javascript framework when values are updated and the node is rebuilt.
> - Element may have been inside an iframe or another context which was refreshed.

What I want to select each object, and open it.

This is the SELECT part from the url:

```
<select id="kategorija" name="kategorija">
<option value="0">Kategorija</option>
<option value="12">Vijesti</option>
<option value="8">Biznis</option>
<option value="5">Sport</option>
<option value="2">Magazin</option>
<option value="7">Lifestyle</option>
<option value="3">Scitech</option>
<option value="6">Auto</option> 
</select>
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox() 

driver.get("http://www.klix.ba/") 

assert "Klix" in driver.title 

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q") 

elem.send_keys("test") 

elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('kategorija'))

all_options = [o.get_attribute('value') for o in select.options]

for x in all_options:
    select.select_by_value(x)
    time.sleep(3)
```

This is the [url](http://www.klix.ba/pretraga?q=test&kategorija=12) where I do my testings.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*The page refreshes itself* when an item is chosen from the dropdown.

You need to "refind" the `select` element on each option select:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('kategorija'))

for index in range(len(select.options)):
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('kategorija'))
    select.select_by_index(index)

    # grab the results
```