# Drop-down selection using XPath Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to select the last option and, I am stuck at this stage. is there any way to directly select a 2000 option by XPath.

Thanks to everyone, I edited my question and, I have come up with an Xpath solution.

Here is the code:

```
    obj = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='pagerA']//div//font//select"))
obj.select_by_value("2000")
```

[image]

Comment: First two lines are Python, the third is a mix between C# and Java/Python. You should also explain what is the problem, *anyone could help me out* is not a question.

Comment: You're using python and there's no `FindElement` method, you mixed up with C#. Use `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "")`.

Comment: `driver.FindElement(By.XPath())` is C#, you want `driver.find_element_by_xpath()`

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited my question. I found this "following::span[1]" somewhere here while I was looking for a proper way to do so.

Comment: I am using Python and, I also tried driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//font[@class='selectPage']")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium (Python) - SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382415/selenium-python-select). Also you can find helpful information about Selenium Python [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html)

Comment: @Sers Thanks for your tips though it didn't work on my case

Comment: Can you share the URL? What error do you get? Update the question with latest code you tried.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share it. It's the company's web server that keeps confidential data.